# Nginx proxy incorrect fastcgi_script_name for static files

Tags: php, nginx, yii2-advanced-app

```
server {
    listen loc.app:80;    

    root /app/frontend/web;

    index index.php;

    location / {        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/admin {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;     
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {    
        #php conf
    }                    
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:81;

    root /app/backend/web;

    index index.php;

    location / {        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.(js|css)$ {    
        echo "$document_root"; # /app/backend/web;

        echo "$fastcgi_script_name"; # /admin/assets/569a8b41/css/bootstrap.css         
        ############################## ISSUE ##############################
        # $fastcgi_script_name must be /assets/569a8b41/css/bootstrap.css #
        ###################################################################
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {    
        #php conf
    }
}
```

http://loc.app/admin - ok 
http://loc.app/admin/style.css - returns 404

How to force nginx to correctly handle static files ?

Answer (score 3):

Static files such as js and css have nothing to do with fastcgi.

However, since the file is in `/admin/assets/569a8b41/css` but your conf has `/app/backend/web` as the document root, then this will never be found and you will always get a 404 since you are asking nginx to look for `/app/backend/web/admin/assets/569a8b41/css/bootstrap.css` which doesn't exist.

Because of the comlexity of your setup, you can add another internal only location block to handle the actual serving of the request and redirect to this from the original location block.

```
location ~ /admin/assets/569a8b41 {
    root /admin/assets/569a8b41;        
}
location ~ ^/admin/(.+)\.(js|css)$ {    
    rewrite ^/admin/(.+)\.css$ /admin/assets/569a8b41/css/$1.css last;
    rewrite ^/admin/(.+)\.js$ /admin/assets/569a8b41/js/$1.js last;
}
```

A request such as `http://loc.app/admin/style.css` will look in `/admin/assets/569a8b41/css/style.css`and if present, it will serve this.

Note that this assumes you have separate `css` and `js` folders under `/admin/assets/569a8b41`.

Comment: That's not what I need. Using a proxy, I tried to avoid "location hell".

Answer (score 1):

İf you use ~ sign it means the following pattern is a Regular Expression so in this case nginx will take the all URI and pass it so you need to get rid of the "admin" part at your backend config, i am asuming that /app/backend/web at this path only admin panel runs so here is my advise:

```
location ~ ^/admin {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;     
}
```

Change this to this:

```
location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;     
}
```

in this case your style.css file shoulbe in /app/backend/web path

as a result when you call
loc.app/admin/style.js

in the background nginx will make this request 127.0.0.1:81/style.css
if you have some css dir in the /app/backend/web then your main url should be loc.app/admin/css/style.js => 127.0.0.1:81/css/style.css file should be in /app/backend/web/css/style.css

i hope this gives an idea.

Answer (score 0):

`proxy_pass` takes the requested uri and sends it to the upstream server. If the uri looks differently on the upstream server you should `rewrite` the uri before passing it to proxy(e.g.: *get rid of the `/admin` part*). But this might not be a good idea for your case, because it seems to me that you also need the `/admin` part for your backend php application to work, since it seems to be declared as a route in your php framework. So, maybe the best solution for you would be to remove the `/admin` part only for static files. Update your nginx configuration for the **backend** server to contain something like this:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
    rewrite ^/admin/(.*) /$1 last;
}
```

make sure you remove the `echo`s which you added.